# Stopping music in java, using JMF

Tags: java, jmf

So i got this code playing music for an RPG-game. The first method plays battle music, the other a fanfare when you win. My problem is that the music stacks and in the end it´s a thousand different battle music and fanfares playing. How do I stop the music when a battle has ended and a fanfare should play, and vice versa?

Here´s the code:

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.media.Format;

import javax.media.Manager;

import javax.media.MediaLocator;

import javax.media.Player;

import javax.media.PlugInManager;

import javax.media.format.AudioFormat;


public class PlayMusic {

    public void playBattle() {

        try{
            Player player = Manager.createPlayer(new MediaLocator(new File("battle.wav").toURI().toURL()));
            player.start();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void playWin() {     


        try{
            Player player = Manager.createPlayer(new MediaLocator(new File("fanfare.wav").toURI().toURL()));
            player.start();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.media.Format;

import javax.media.Manager;

import javax.media.MediaLocator;

import javax.media.Player;

import javax.media.PlugInManager;

import javax.media.format.AudioFormat;


public class PlayMusic {

 Player battlePlayer = Manager.createPlayer(new MediaLocator(new File("battle.wav").toURI().toURL()));
  Player winPlayer = Manager.createPlayer(new MediaLocator(new File("fanfare.wav").toURI().toURL()));


    public void playBattle() {

        try{

            battlePlayer.start();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void playWin() {     


        try{

            winPlayer.start();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

 public void stopWin() {     


        try{

            winPlayer.stop();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

 public void stopBattle() {     


        try{

            battlePlayer.stop();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense :) But when I try to compile i get" unreported exception java.net.MalformedURLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown" Tried to make the battlePlayer and winPlayer to private fields, but no luck.

Comment: Player battlePlayer =null;
  Player winPlayer = null; Public PlayMusic(){try{ battlePlayer = Manager.createPlayer(new MediaLocator(new File("battle.wav").toURI().toURL()));
  winPlayer = Manager.createPlayer(new MediaLocator(new File("fanfare.wav").toURI().toURL()));}catch(Exception e){}}

Comment: just define players in start of class and intialize them in constructors their u can catch exceptions

Comment: last question tho, trying to reset the song when it stops. Tried setMicroSecondPosition(0) and setFrameWorkPosition(0), but it seems like JMF doesn´t have those calls...